# Creating a variables (one-line if command line Python)

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, if-statement

Im trying to create a variable with an if statement. Basically, the new column `'Region'` has to take as based if the column `'State'`. If State is PR then Region is PR else region is US
I tried the following:

```
(unfunded_accounts['Region']=='US' if unfunded_accounts['State']!='PR' else unfunded_accounts['Region']=='PR')
```

but it says

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "one line if command". That's a ternary expression and *not* a substitute for a normal `if`/`else` clause. Use the usual method. Also you use `=` for assigning values to variables.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is like this:

Given input df:

```
    State
0   PR
1   FF
```

Try:

```
df.loc[df['State']=='PR','Region'] = 'PR'
df.fillna('US',inplace=True))
```

Which prints:

```
   State    Region
0   PR      PR
1   FF      US
```

If you really want to go the oneline if/else way, then you can try below:

```
df['Region'] = df.apply(lambda row:'US' if row['State']!='PR' else 'PR', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one-line comprehension format. So supposing you have a dataframe like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

unfunded_accounts = {'State': ["PR", "AZ", "WA", "PR"]}
unfunded_accounts = pd.DataFrame(unfunded_accounts)
```

All you need to do now is the following one line that checks the `State` column and if the row value equals `PR`, assigns it to the newly built `Region` column and else assigns `US` to it:

```
unfunded_accounts["Region"] = ["PR" if state == "PR" else "US" for state in unfunded_accounts["State"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want this:

```
unfunded_accounts['Region']=('PR' if unfunded_accounts['State']=='PR' else 'US')
```

Answer (score -1):

I just checked your code and i found bugs there.
Please try with this code.

```
unfunded_accounts['Region']=('US' if unfunded_accounts['State']!='PR' else 'PR')
```